# Polymorphism in Python via abstraction

Tags: python

I'm trying to achieve polymorphism in python via abstraction. Here's my code:

```
class Animal:
    def talk(self):
        print('Hello')

class Dog(Animal):
    def talk(self):
        print('Bark')

class Cat(Animal):
    def talk(self):
        print('meow')

myObj = Dog()
print(myObj.talk())
```

this achieves the purpose except when I create an object and print, I get the following output:

```
Bark
None
```

I was expecting to get just `Bark`. Can anyone explain to me why `None` is also printed?

Comment: You should call the method but not print `myObj.talk()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`None` is the return value of the `talk()` method, since this method does not return any value explicitly. If you execute `myObj.talk()` (without `print()`) you will get `Bark` only.